# creating one exe with embedded dll

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll

I'm trying to create a downloader and it needs to be one single executable.

With the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025127/how-to-embed-dll-from-class-project-into-my-project-in-vb-net) I managed to link my DLL files to the executable.
But, one DLL uses a DLL of it's own and I can't seem to get it embedded as well.

I tried to add the CORE module ([from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678581/vb-net-embedded-dll-in-another-dll-as-embedded-resource)) and I call the EnsureInitialized() sub from the function that needs the DLL.
But for some reason I keep getting the message that the DLL could not be loaded.
If I call the assembly.load function, I get the DLL not found error on that line.
The DLL is embedded as a resource and also in the references (but no local copy, since I don't want that).

Why is it not loading my DLL?
I even embedded it in to my downloader executable and load it there, but the DLL that needs it, is not loading it or using the loaded one.

Any suggestions?

The code I used is the two mentioned answers.

rg,
Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest approach to this is to use [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx). You run this from the command line specifying the source exe and the DLLs you want to merge and it produces a resultant exe:

```
ilmerge /target:winexe /out:c:\MyMergedExe.exe c:\MySourceExe.exe C:\MyDLL1.dll C:\MyDLL2.dll
```